# Pause animation in interaction for a particular time in css

Tags: javascript, css

I want to pause animation for a particular time between repeating animation

I will fetch data from json file, e.g. 1s pause, 2s pause, 3s pause, 4s pause.

I can only use javascript/css hacks to pause animation.

```
Animation is purely made in CSS. 

https://codepen.io/prax/pen/WORMEJ
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In whatever your "fetch data" function is, apply `animation-play-state: paused;` to the elements you want to pause, then remove that when you're ready to un-pause.

Here's a demo.

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',function() {
  // fetch data & pause & setTimeout to un-pause
  document.getElementById('div').classList.add('pause');
  var seconds = 1; // use a different value to pause for different times
  var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('div').classList.remove('pause');
  },seconds * 1000)
})
```

```css
div {
  animation: foo 3s infinite;
}
@keyframes foo {
  50% {
    color: red;
  }
}
.pause {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">asdf</div>
<button id="button">button</button>
```

Comment: I am getting error
    index.html:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: @PrakharMaheshwari well you don't need to use that part of the code, sorry if that was unclear. I added a button so that you could trigger the pause. You would just take the contents of the `addEventListener` function and put it on your page when you "fetch data" - whatever that is.